# Mac Mini's fan is not speeding up when it's under pressure

Tags: mac-mini, performance, apple-silicon, temperature

I have a Mac Mini 2020 with M1 chip. Fan is always working around 1700 rpm no matter the CPU temperature.  Even if CPU temperature is 80 degree celsius, it works at the same speed as if it was only 25C.

And after a while CPU starts throttling until I speed up the fan manually.

I don't want to do this manually anymore. Is there a something wrong with my Mac?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can you tell the CPU is throttling?

Comment: @mmmmmm the Mac starts lagging even when I try to switch windows until I speed up the fan. After the fan speed increased it is working fine again.

Comment: You might consider phoning Apple about this one, as this does not sound like normal behavior. Perhaps they got the thermal paste applied poorly in manufacturing or something

Comment: What mechanism or application are you using when you "I speed up the fan manually."? Is it possible that application has applied an override to default behaviors?

Comment: @cmason I don't believe it's about thermal paste. Because the problem relates to fan. But I will call the support anyway. As you said this is not normal.

Comment: @Freiheit stats or iStats and now Macs Fan Control. Probably, it cannot override anything without my permission or password. Also, I am using these on my Macbook Pro but it is working just fine.

Comment: How did you get those graphs? If it was via iStat Menus, note that that itself gives you a way to control the fan rules. (Could you have changed them that way, inadvertently?)

Comment: @gidds Yes, those was from iStats but I just installed it to take the screenshots. There is nothing installed to cause this behavior. I usually use stats and when I try to switch manual fan controls, it asks my root password. I will revive the Mac this weekend and then call the support if the problem continues. I've been using Mac Mini M1 since it's launched. I thought, M1 wasn't good enough and fan was always working because this machine does not have a battery but I realised last month; if I speed up the fan, Mac is working how I expected once.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmmm, maybe you should look at `Macs Fan Control` app to set fan rules and try to manually start your fans to make sure they are still functional.

[Download Macs Fan Control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download)